# Custom button with drawable background: Padding difference in Android 4 vs. Android 2.3

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

The following code is for displaying a custom button in Android. Unfortunately, all those padding values at those different places affect the way the button is rendered only for Android 2.3, but on Android 4.X it has no effect, i.e. the padding is always the same, regardless of what you set here. Why?

**The layout XML:**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/sample_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_caption"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    style="@style/CustomButton"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

**The style:**

```
<style name="CustomButton">
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:padding">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_button</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

**The drawable:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#60ff0000" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ffffff" />
            <corners
                android:radius="4dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="6dp"
                android:top="6dp"
                android:right="6dp"
                android:bottom="6dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid
                android:color="#90ff0000" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ffffff" />
            <corners
                android:radius="4dp" />
            <padding
                android:left="6dp"
                android:top="6dp"
                android:right="6dp"
                android:bottom="6dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

When I set all these padding values to a small value such as 2, the button is shown almost without a padding on Android 2.3.3 (probably correct) but with a padding that is still very large on Android 4.X (probably wrong). Can someone see why?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Android's Holo theme sets a minWidth and minHeight in the [system styles.xml resource for `Holo.Widget.Button`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml#L1529) which specifies rules in addition to those used by the non-holo button, [`Widget.Button`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml#L314). Even with a small button title, the button will take up 64x48dip in Android 4.2.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/sample_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Z"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:minHeight="1dp"
    android:minWidth="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    style="@style/CustomButton"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Comment: Happy to help - the moral of this story is to always check the styling/code on Github for clues regarding default behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

David's answer may indeed be the issue.

However, I would think that if the min width and height are 48/64dp, changing padding from 6dp to 2pd or vice versa should not make a big difference, unless you actual button is already right at that 48/64 dp size.

If this is the case, I wonder if it could be a bug on Android.
If no padding on the View is specified, the padding in the background drawable is used (if any)
If padding on the View is specified, any padding in the background drawable is ignored and the padding set on the View is used.

Just for the sake of it, have you tried to make the paddings really large instead of small and see if that has any effect?

Comment: You might be right. Without knowing the value of `@string/button_caption` and seeing exactly what Marco sees, one can only speculate. I agree that it could be a bug, though I'd be very surprised if the drawable padding was causing it. That padding value should only affect the drawing of the background.

Comment: Thank you! It could have been a bug, you were right. I had to check it - and it is *not*. Everything is working fine and the explanation to this issue is what David wrote.